# Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s)

Tags: import, magento-2.1.7

I'm importing products via csv and get the following error:

```
Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s)
```

what I've noticed is that error appears for specific images although they are exists and no thing in logs regarding this.

**Note**: import directory is mounted on S3 bucket